# Matrix-vector multiplication from decimal to binary

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, binary-data

I have to implement in python3.6 a matrix-vector multiplication onto a system that can only handle objects with binary states (in the following 0 or 1). I simply have to do: `y = Rx` where `R` is a square NxN matrix (in general non-symmetric) and `x` is a vector with N elements.

The way I'm approaching the problem is to convert the vector x to a tuple of unsigned integers. Using numpy uint8, it becomes a vector of 8N elements, e.g.:

```
e_1 = (1,0,0,...,0)
e_2 = (0,1,0,...,0)
...
e_N = (0,0,0....,1)
```

My problem is how to convert the matrix `R` to a binary representation such that I can still perform a matrix multiplication to obtain the binary representation of `y`, which I can later convert to decimal.

For example:

```
x = [10, 25, 20]
R = [[2, 1, 0],
     [1, 4, 0],
     [0, 0, 2]]

x_b = np.unpackbits(x)  # (4)*8 = (24)
R_b = some_function(R)

# calculation in decimal representation
y = np.dot(R, x)

# calculation in binary representation
y_b = np.dot(R_b, x_b)
z = np.packbits( y_b )
```

If the procedure makes sense, `y` and `z` should be the same. 
Now, I recall from linear algebra that the binary vectors mentioned above have the same structure of the standard basis of a vector space. So, I thought that by repeatedly applying `R` to each of those vectors, I should be able to create a binary representation of `R`. My implementation of `some_function` is:

```
def some_function(R, n_bits=8):
  n_cols = R.shape[0]
  n_vectors = n_cols*n_bits
  R_b = np.zeros([n_vectors, n_vectors], dtype='uint8')
  for i in range(n_vectors):
     v_bin = np.zeros(n_vectors, dtype='uint8')
     v_bin[i] = 1

     v_dec = np.packbits(v_bin)

     u_dec = np.dot(R, v_dec)
     u_bin = np.unpackbits(u_dec)

     R_b[:, i] = u_bin

  return R_b
```

However, this seems to work only if the matrix is diagonal, and if the elements on the diagonal are even. I'm quite lost at this point, but I have the feeling that this problem has been solved already long ago.

Cheers,
Riccardo

Comment: what's the intended result of [[1,1],[1,1]] * [[1,1],[1,1]] ?

Comment: I assume that if you have a 2, you have to change it 0 and carry a bit to the element to its left, i.e. ```02=10```. I'd say ```[[1,1],[1,1]] * [[1,1],[1,1]] = [[0,0],[0,0]]``` but I may be wrong.

Comment: You're going to have to resolve that. My first guess would have been change addition to logical or, change multiplication to logical and.